# Creating database in PouchDB

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, cordova, pouchdb

I am currently using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 & Cordova for mobile development.

I tried by going through PouchDB documentation and use whatever they gave

```
function insertDB() {
    var db = new PouchDB("todos");
    var remoteDB = new PouchDB("http://localhost:5984/todos");

    db.put({
        _id: 'mydoc',
        title: 'Heroes'
    }).then(function (response) {
        // handle response
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    PouchDB.sync('remoteDB', 'http://localhost:5984/todos');
}
```

I used a button to invoke the insertDB() function, but I have errors.

```
 <button onclick="insertDB()">Click Me!</button>
```

I kept getting error saying localDB not defined, PouchDB not defined. I know I did wrong because I've very new to PouchDB and I've never used it before.

May I know where I did wrong in?

Comment: looks like you have a typo on your code

`PouchDB.sync('remoteDB', 'http://localhost:5984/todos');`

should be 
`PouchDB.sync(db, remoteDb);`

Comment: @twilson63 However, I am still getting error on PouchDB not defined. May I know why?

Comment: .@fiatjaf Did you not see that I answered to my own answer? Does that not mean that I tried to debug on my own? Does it? If that's the case, I have nothing to say. It's not typo,  my friend. I followed the guide in PouchDB web, they gave me this line of code. So it didn't work, I didn't know why. But I TRIED and TRIED, so I answered to my own question in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I realized that I linked the min.js of pouchdb but it couldn't find the file, thus the error of undefined. I then used `<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/pouchdb/5.4.5/pouchdb.min.js"></script>` and problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

not defined means your pouchdb package is not initilized correctly
use npm or cdn

```
   const PouchDB = require('pouchdb').default;
```

Everything is correct expect below line (Your Syntax is wrong)

```
var db = new PouchDB("todos");
var remoteDB = new PouchDB("http://localhost:5984/todos");
PouchDB.sync('remoteDB', 'http://localhost:5984/todos');
```

Correction

```
var db = new PouchDB("todos");//localdb
var remoteDB = new PouchDB("http://localhost:5984/todos");
PouchDB.sync('db', 'http://localhost:5984/todos');
```

in pouchdb when you call below line ,db will create.if db is not present

it update db ,if already present

```
 var db = new PouchDB("todos");
```

so the above single line is used to create or update data by using put function
(if u pass _id and _rev) it update your db

if not pass _id and _rev it insert the new line

import your pouchdb

```
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb').default;
```

then

```
function insertDB() {
    var db = new PouchDB("todos");
    var remoteDB = new PouchDB("http://localhost:5984/todos");

    db.put({
        _id: 'mydoc',
        title: 'Heroes'
    }).then(function (response) {
        // handle response
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    PouchDB.sync('db', 'http://localhost:5984/todos');
}
```